# Mixing AngularJS with Symfony2 (Routing + Twig) or better us another JS-Framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, twig

Is it possible and "clean" to mix AngularJS with the Symfony2 routing and twig?

Symfony should handle to general routing, so by clicking on a menu link to site reloads. But parts like commenting, rating & co should be more usable and more modern with AngularJS + AJAX.

Is this a clean way to implement such things? I think it could be also solved with jQuery and without AngularJS - or another JS-Framework?

Comment: most people don't mix 2 frameworks and trend is to only use back end as API and create single page applications with angular. Question however is off topic as it is opinionated and asking for recommendations

Answer (score 7):

I am maintaining around 10 projects written in Symfony2 and angular. Anybody, feel free to edit this post and improve it.

1. I am not using Symfony `assetic` function. Instead I am using `gulp`. Below is my `gulp.js` file. It use Babel.js to transform es6 into es5, then split all files into one, and put in `web` directory.

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    babel   = require("gulp-babel"),
    concat  = require('gulp-concat'),
    clean   = require('gulp-clean'),
    uglify  = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/compiled', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('babel', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(["src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/angular/app.js", "src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/angular/**/*.js"])
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/compiled"));
});

gulp.task('merge', ['babel'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/compiled/**/*.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('angular-compiled.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js/compiled'));
});

gulp.task('compress', ['merge'], function () {
    return gulp.src('web/js/compiled/angular-compiled.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js/compiled'));
});

gulp.task("default", ['merge']);
```

2. All angular files are placed in `src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/angular` directory and compiled into one `.js` file, so I don't have to include each .js file into each .twig file
3. In `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` file I have

```
<script>
    angular
        .module('configuration', [])
        .constant('BASE_END_POINT', '{{ app.request.baseUrl }}')
        .constant('USER', '{{ app.user || default() }}');
</script>
```

`BASE_END_POINT` is app base url to make API cals. This is something like proxy to pass data from Symfony to Angular. In the `body` I placed `ng-app`. Just to prevent including it in each twig file.

4. In `src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/angular` I have small base angular configuration:

```
    //app.js
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('app', [
            'configuration'
        ]);

        app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        }]);

    }());
```

where `configuration` is a module with my constants from base.html.twig. `$interpolateProvider` change default angular braces `{{}}` to `[[]]`, to prevent twig and angular conflicts.

5. In `src/MainBundle/Resources/public/js/angular` directory I always keep below structure:

[image]

Each segment has new directory and in it:

- factory
- controller
- service
- model etc..

  6. In the controller I always communicate with twig files. For example this is controller:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('ml')
        .controller('WineCtrl', WineCtrl);

    WineCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'WineFactory'];

    function WineCtrl($scope, WineFactory) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.send = (selected) => {
            WineFactory.send(selected);
        };

    }
}());
```

7. `WineFactory.send(selected);` Here I am sending some data to factory. And from factory to Symfony2 API

```
angular
    .module('ml')
    .factory('WineFactory', WineFactory);

WineFactory.$inject = ['$http', 'BASE_END_POINT'];

function WineFactory($http, BASE_END_POINT) {
    var self = this;

    self.send = function (selected) {
        return $http.post(BASE_END_POINT + "/wines", {payload: selected})
            .then((response) => console.info(response));
    };

    return self;
}
```

8. Symfony routing looks like this:

```
// VIEWS

wine.view:
    path:     /wine
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Default:wine }

// API

api.send.wine:
    path:     /wines
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Wine:send }
    methods:  [POST]
```

9. To be continued

Check my github opensource projects, you may find something interesting https://github.com/ssuperczynski/symfony2-azure-ml

Answer (score 0):

Both frameworks work very nicely together (all frameworks actually), because they operate on a completely different level.

AngularJS operates in the browser, while Symfony operates on the server. This means that Symfony is very good in providing the API backend, while Angular is very good in calling this API and showing it to the user.

When developing such apps, think as if you create 2 seperate apps. Let Symfony purely handle the API routes and manage all other routes using Angular.